# retrieving POST information from a cURL request

Tags: php, curl

i'm supposed to come up with a dialog with another developer's script (from another company)

so, here's the basic rundown:
1) i send a request to http://some-url.com?param=foo
2) he sends me info back in the POST fields

the question i have is, how do i directly access the POST array that is sent back to me?

lets say his POST field is ?param1=foo&param2=bar

and lets say my code is something like

```
$url = 'http://some-url.com?param=foo';
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$curl_result = curl_exec($curl_session);
```

my intuition sometimes off when it comes to these things.  i've seen something referring to $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA or to php://input, but neither say how to actually use them.

my intuition says that after i've done the curl_exec($curl_session), that $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA['param1'] and $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA['param2'] will be what i'll be using.

am i right?  or could someone steer my ship in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be some confusion.  "POST fields" are an optional part of an HTTP *request* not an HTTP *response*.

It appears that you'll be sending a request.  Therefore he'll be returning a response. This response may contain an easily parseable set of key-value pairs, but they wouldn't be "POST anything".

Answer (score 0):

The Response is in $curl_result ;) But what are you trying to do? Are you trying to actually POST the fields or somthing else?

You should read up on the [curl docs](http://php.net/curl).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It seems like terminology is getting confused here.